# "{Item:{id:}" data testing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I test for items with a data value, like gray dye or purple wool, using the `{Item:id}` command?

I have tried using `{Item:{id:minecraft:dye:7}}` and `{Item:{id:351/7}}`

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `Damage` tag. It is of type short, so you also need to suffix the number with an 's':

```
{Item:{id:minecraft:dye,Damage:7s}}
```